# Accessing data structures created inside a function?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, struct, malloc

For example, I have a function:

```
void build()
{
   struct Node *node;
   node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
}
```

Is it possible to access the pointer "node" from the outside?

Comment: @geoxile can you pass pointer as an argument?

Comment: No unfortunately the function is already established, I just have to use it. vz0's global variable solution is the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C is a pretty straightforward and simple language. The only choice you have is to explicitlly put the node value somewhere, eiter:

1. global variable
2. parameters on the function
3. return value

Options 2 and 3 are the most common ones. As an argument to the function:

```
void build(struct Node **node_param)
{
   struct Node *node;
   node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
   *node_param = node;
}
```

For option 3 can be simply:

```
struct Node * build()
{
   struct Node *node;
   node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
   return node;
}
```

You can either create a standalone variable or create an struct with more fields in case you have many values to return from your function.

Comment: I have another question about global variables If my struct Node has another field struct Node *next and I create a global variable called struct Node *root (with root->next initialized as NULL) will I be able to change root->next to a different value?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access the pointer "node" from the outside?

No, not this exact pointer since you don't know th memory address returned by malloc. You can access the `Node` instance pointed to by `*node` if you return initialized pointer out of the function or you pass it as an argument to this function, initialize inside the function and use after this.

example:

```
// pass pointer to pointer, so we will change original pointer not a copy
void build( struct Node **nodePtr)
{
   struct Node *node;
   node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node)); 
   //   ^^^^
   // no need to cast result of malloc in C
   *nodePtr = node;
   // the rest...
}
```